# How to add GreenDroid to an existing Android Studio project?

Tags: android, git, android-studio, greendroid

I'm trying to add GreenDroid to an existing project, but I can't figure it out.

[The instructions weren't very helpful.](https://github.com/cyrilmottier/GreenDroid/blob/master/README.mdown)

I was able to download it by using: *VCS>Checkout from Version Control>Git*, but Android Studio added it as a standalone project not a library I can implement into my existing app.

Comment: have look  this https://cyrilmottier.com/2010/05/14/introduction-to-the-greendroid-library/

Comment: @hemant-parmar I'm stuck on step 2 of that link you gave me. I'm on a Windows machine. How do I `Go to the scripts/ folder of the GreenDroid folder. Run the script named “greendroid.py” (make sure you can run it - chmod +x greendroid.py) to apply the library to your project : ./greendroid.py apply <project_directory>`                                                
                                                                                                                  Is this something I can do through Android Studio?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Go to the scripts/ folder of the GreenDroid folder. Run the script named “greendroid.py” (make sure you can run it - `chmod +x greendroid.py`) to apply the library to your project : `./greendroid.py apply <project_directory>`

You should be able to try on Windows it with:

- `git bash`
- python in your `$PATH`

Then you can see of the same project, when opened in Android Studio, has the right library.

Comment: Thanks for the answer VonC. But greendroid.py has been removed from the library. The GitHub page is saying to use the ADT Plugin for Eclipse, but it says nothing about how to install the library using Android Studio. Cyril Mottier, the creator of GreenDroid stopped maintaining the project. So, does this mean I'm just shit out of luck?

Comment: @ngx311 Yes, the project seems obsolete and says so in its README.